# show that for any n $\in$ $\Bbb N$ , if n $\ge$ 2, then $\prod_\limits{i=2}^n $ $\left( 1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)$ = $\frac{n+1}{2n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to use mathematical induction to show that for any n $\in$ $\Bbb N$ , 
if n  $\ge$ 2, then $\prod_\limits{i=2}^n $ $\left( 1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)$ = $\frac{n+1}{2n}$

Comment: What do you mean by $(n+1)/(2-n)$ when $n=2?$

Comment: The right value should be $\frac{n+1}{2n}$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS You're right!, Edited it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way of "seeing" what's going on :
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{i^2}) &= \prod_{i=2}^n (\frac{i^2-1}{i^2}) = \prod_{i=2}^n (\frac{(i-1)(i+1)}{i^2}) \\
&= \frac{1\times3}{2^2}\times \frac{2\times4}{3^2}\times \frac{3\times5}{4^2}\times \frac{4\times6}{5^2}\times \dots\times \frac{(n-2)\times n}{(n-1)^2}\times \frac{(n-1)\times(n+1)}{n^2} \\
&= \frac{1\times(n+1)}{2\times n}
\end{align} 
The "induction" step just consists in having your formula right :
$$\prod_{i=2}^{n+1} (1-\frac{1}{i^2}) = \prod_{i=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{i^2}) \times (1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}) \underset{\mathscr P_n}{=} \frac{n+1}{2n}\times \frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{n+2}{2(n+1)}$$